# Removing percent sign in ggsurvplot R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I have the following code where I am building a survival curve with percentages instead of proportions. I am also breaking the survival time by tens. I would like to remove the percent symbols from the following plot as I would like to add that to the ylab title of the plot instead.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
data(lung)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, axes.offset = FALSE,
           break.y = 0.10,
           surv.scale = c("percent"),
           xlim = c(0, 1050))
```

Comment: Why not `plot(fit, col=2:3, xlab="t", ylab="prob.")`?

Comment: Are you looking for `surv.scale = "default",` ?

Comment: The default option shows the proportions. I meant the percentages without the percent symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to make the plot and then add a `scale_y_continuous` call which replaces the y-axis with whatever you want.

```
plot <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, axes.offset = FALSE,
           xlim = c(0, 1050),
           ylab = "Survival Probability (%)")
plot$plot <- plot$plot + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.1), labels = seq(0,100,by=10))
plot
```

[image]

Why don't the package maintainers let you do this directly with `+`?